# How to copy files using terminal to specific subdirectories with the same name?

Tags: centos, terminal

I want to copy 4 files to all subdirectories with the same name. Example one directory is in

```
/toplevel/images/sources
```

and another is in

```
/toplevel/documents/files/sources
```

and any other subdirectory named "sources" should have all these files as well. From the "toplevel" directory, how can I use the 
cp command to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all directories using the `find` command, for example:

```bsh
$ find /toplevel -name sources -type d
/toplevel/documents/files/sources
/toplevel/images/sources
```

`-name sources` tells `find` to only show results which have the name `sources`, and `-type d` filters that to only show directories. Combine that with a for loop, and you can copy all files in directory `/myfiles` (for example) into them:

```bsh
$ for directory in $(find /toplevel -name sources -type d); do cp /myfiles/* "$directory"; done
$ tree /toplevel
/toplevel
├── documents
│   └── files
│       └── sources
│           ├── file_1
│           ├── file_2
│           ├── file_3
│           └── file_4
└── images
    └── sources
        ├── file_1
        ├── file_2
        ├── file_3
        └── file_4

5 directories, 8 files
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.